# ADO.NET Entity Data Model template missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I currently have an ASP.NET .NET Core 2.0 application in visual studio 2017 but I can't seem to add ADO.NET Entity framework models despite installing the necessary components outlined in this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

In fact, I don't even have the Visual C# or Data dropdown on the left as you can see here:

[image: img]

However I am able to access these file templates if I create a plain console application. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must be missing some desktop dev VS components

Comment: [EDMX is not supported in EF Core any longer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686177/1466046)